# ¿Cómo hago para que un registro nuevo tenga un rol por defecto que este en la DB con Shinobi?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, users-roles

¡Un cordial saludo! Tengo el paquete shinobi para roles y permisos pero quiero agregar un rol por defecto cuando se registren. En la documentación de shinobi sale el siguiente código:

```
  auth()->user()->assignRoles('cliente')
```

Pero cuando lo agrego al controlador de registro me aparece un error que es el siguente:

**Call to a member function assignRoles() on null**

Aca les dejo el código de mí controlador de registro, a ver si me pudieran ayudar a resolver el problema. El rol que quiero accionar por defecto se llama "client":

````
namespace rapygiro\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use rapygiro\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use rapygiro\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use rapygiro\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \rapygiro\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            auth()->user()->assignRoles('client'),

        ]);
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Hola. Creo que la manera correcta de usar esa función sería algo como: $user = User::create([........]); $user->assignRoles('client'); Porque el ejemplo dice algo como "del usuario autenticado, trae al usuario y asígnale este rol"

Comment: gracias, pude resolver!

Answer (score 0):

Trata de hacer la asignación directamente después del cierre del método `create`:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])->assignRole('client');
    }
```